# Positive integral of $fg$ everywhere for all $g \in C_C^0(\mathbb R^n )$ implies positive function a.e

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f$ be an locally integrable function on the measure space $(\mathbb R^n,S,\mu)$, with $\mu$ be a radon measure proof that

\begin{align}
\text{If }\int_{\mathbb R^n} f g\, d\mu \geq 0\text{ for all }g\in C_C^0(\mathbb R^n)\text{ s.t } g \geq 0 \text{ then }f \geq 0\text{ a.e.}
\end{align}
I see clear that the reasoning of these problem is by contradiction, then i suppose that $\mu(f^{-1}(- \infty ,0)) >0$ is easy to see that
$$f^{-1}(- \infty ,0)=\bigcup_{n} f^{-1}(-\infty, -1/n)$$
then i take $n_0$ s.t $\mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, -1/n_0))>0$ now my problem is how i can construct a continuous compact supported function $g$ s.t. $spt(g) \subset f^{-1}(-\infty, -1/n)$ $g \geq0$ for find the contradiction
Another aproach to i think is using something like the density of $C_C^0(\mathbb R^n)$ but i not sure

**EDIT**

I think in a new approach:

By contradiction, sup. exists $A$ st. $ \mu(A)>0$ and $f<0$ in A, then like $\mu$ is Radon there exists $K$ compact such that $K \subset A$ and $\infty> \mu(K)>\frac{\mu(A)}{2}>0$ now like $\infty >\mu(K)$ then exists a sequence of compact supported continuous functions $( \psi _n )_n$ such that $0 \leq \psi_n \leq 1$ and $\psi_n \to 1_K$ then by dominated convergence theorem (I have doubts in these step)
$$\int f \psi_n d \mu \to \int f 1_K d\mu = \int_K f d \mu <0$$
But by hypothesis $0 \leq \int f\psi_n d \mu$, $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ then
$$0 \leq \int f \psi_n d \mu <0$$
And hence these is a contradiction.\

These proof is correct? Any hint or help I will be very grateful.

Comment: How about this: $f\ast\rho_{\varepsilon}\to f$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ ($\rho_{\varepsilon}$'s are mollifiers) so you get a subsequence converging to $f$ a.e. but the subsequence is always non-negative. Therefore, $f\geq0$ a.e. .

Comment: @PNDas i think to is a good aproach but i try to show these only with properties of radon measures and density of $C_c^0$

Answer (score 1):

This proof uses Complex measures and Riesz Representation Theorem.

By Theorem 2.14 of Rudin's RCA, there exists  a positive regular measure $\nu$ such that  $\int fgd\mu=\int gd\nu$ for all $g \in C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$. Let $\lambda=\nu-fd\mu$. Then, $\int gd\lambda=0$ for all $g \in C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$. This implies that $\lambda =0$. One way of proving this is to use the fact that $ C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$ is dense in $L^{1}(\lambda)$. (This is also proved in Rusin's RCA). Clearly, $fd\mu=\lambda$ implies $f \geq 0$ a.e. $[\mu]$.

Comment: I am unable to give exact references from Rudin's book because what I have is an Indian edition of the book.

Comment: thanks for your answer i think to is very clear, but i try to show these fact without using the Riesz theorem